# Windows server 2012 guest + centos host + IBM server x3650

Tags: windows, xen, ibm

I was told by **IBM** sales that **x3650** doesn't support **windows server 2012**. I feel it's ridiculous as **x3650** is their enterprise model, just one level below its highest class **x3850** in their **system x** series.

Is it possible that I use centos as host to install **XEN** and visualize **windows server 2012**. Can it be done? **Vmware ESXi** is great but its kind of expensive for small online company like us.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct, since [they say](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/common/ssi/ecm/en/xss03102usen/XSS03102USEN.PDF) that they support Windows 2012 across the X line.  If you go online and try to buy a 3650 M4, the customization options include Windows 2012.

Regardless, yes, you can run 2012 in a VM.

Also, you're not correct in claiming that ESXi is kind of expensive. It's [actually free.](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/faq.html)

Comment: yes, the VMware hypervisor is free, but in order to use it to an acceptable level, vCenter and other figure costs money. So that is why .

Comment: Well, given that you didn't list any requirements, none of us have any idea what you mean by "acceptable." If you need a standalone VM host, ESXi works perfectly well.

Comment: ESXi is 'fake' free. you have buy vCenter and some other management tool in order to save work and have central management control. having ESXi itself is kind of not useful.

Comment: Hamilton, what features does Xen have (for free) that ESXi doesn't?